# Looking for a dictionary with standard American English example for foreign learners

Tags: discussion

Here is the thing. As a foreign learner, for example, when I look up sticker, I also need to learn common usage and scenario for it. This is what I mean standard examples. Is there a specific verb for sticker to stick it somewhere? Or Do I use some universal verbs to put, use, place, set, lay a sticker somewhere? Is it a strange and redundant usage to stick a sticker? Although people get what I mean, but if the usage is not common, I get low grade in TOFEL. Natives can learn it from daily life, but I don't have it. In my country people don't speak English. Not only for TOFEL, I find that this has become the key people think I speak fluently or not.

Here is the problem.

MW learner dictionary: nothing
http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sticker

MW dictionary: example doesn't help. It is automatically collected online. The first five sentence is all norm, without a clear scenario. Foreigner learner will get lost trying to understand the scenarios in so many words as I did. 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sticker

Oxford: nothing
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sticker?q=sticker

longman: so far the most foreigner friendly I can find. I learn tear off, earn, peal off, put a sticker. But another problem, Longman is a British dictionary, and there will be lots of British usage I cannot distinguish and may confuse TOFEL judge. I mean, if the British usage is said with a beautiful British accent and with few mistakes, even if judge doesn't know the usage, one will still be convinced. But if with my foreign accent and with other mistakes, judge will not be convinced, and I have no chance to prove it is a standard British usage. So, is there any American English online dictionary that provides standard usage example? 
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sticker

Comment: I think Longman is going to be your best bet. I haven't found too many things in Longman that don't apply to American English, and the few that do are usually labeled `British English` (see the entry for [biscuit](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/biscuit), for example.

Comment: Yeah, the LDOCE labels things as British or American, and it provides both British and American pronunciation for each entry as well.